# What is the location where they make rum called?

Tags: rum

Beer is made in Breweries, wine in Wineries, where is rum made? I have a friend who says rummery but that is marked as a misspelling. I asked google and they said Barbados. Does anyone know?

Comment: Maybe a Distillery?

Comment: I know,  My "basement".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spirits, such as vodka, whisky and also rum, are produced in a distillery.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the location where they make rum called?**

The simplest answer would be a **distillery**!

However another possibility does exist.

Unofficially, [Porcopedia](https://ymir.gamepedia.com/Porcopedia:About) states that a [**rummery**](https://ymir.gamepedia.com/Rumery) is an Alcohol production building. it is like the Cider Mill, Wine cellar and Brewery. At best this would be an *urban definition* and resembles the imaginary than true reality. Thus a distillery is the proper definition as to where rum is made.

> The Rummery is an Alcohol production building. it is like the Cider Mill, Wine cellar and Brewery.
>
> The Rummery makes Rum. - [Rumery](https://ymir.gamepedia.com/Rumery)

Comment: The definition of **rumery** only applies to the 4X multiplayer strategy game *Ymir*.

Comment: @marianoju That is why I stated it as **unofficially**!